# Subdomínio acessando apenas recursos específicos com Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api

Estou usando o Rails 4.2.2

Tenho o seguinte código no arquivo config/routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
    namespace :api, constraints: { subdomain: 'api' }, path: '/' do
        resources :users
    end

    root "pages#home"

    resources :users
    resources :posts
end
```

O que se passa é o seguinte:

Visitando o domínio `dominio.com` eu não consigo acessar a API, até aqui tudo bem.

O problema surge ao visitar `api.dominio.com`, queria apenas ter acesso ao recurso `users` que se encontra no *namespace* `:api` e nada mais. Mas acontece o contrário. mesmo usando o subdomínio `api.dominio.com` eu consigo acessar a root e outros recursos fora dele como o `:posts`.

Comment: Tenste dessa forma `namespace :api, path: '/', constraints: { subdomain: 'api' } do` e coloque apos `resources :posts` (por ultimo).